# How would I go about placing a GameObject on another object's surface while matching the rotation? Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, game-physics, instantiation

I'm making a game where you build, and when I try to place a GameObject on another one's surface it uses global rotation and not local, however I'm trying to get the placed GameObject's rotation to match the other one. This is hard because I also want to have the placed GameObject's be facing away from the surface, if that makes sense.

I've tried using a raycast hit normal to get the placed GameObject facing the right way, and that works only partly. Its up direction is correct, but the other axis's are not orientated to match the other object. Here's the code:

```cs
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(cameraTransform.position, cameraTransform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, buildingRange, buildable.value))
{
    //Indicator to show where the item will be placed
    buildBall.SetActive(true);
    buildBall.transform.position = hit.point;

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //Create the item
        GameObject buildItem = Instantiate(currentItem, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);

        //Set the item's position
        buildItem.transform.position = hit.point;

        //Rotate the item so that it faces away from the other object
        buildItem.transform.up = hit.normal;

        {Connect the buildItem object to the hit.collider.gameObject}
    }
}
```

I've spent many hours trying numerous solutions, this one yields the closest result.
Here are some pics:

This is what is intended, all blocks are orientated correctly:
[image: This solution works if the mass does not rotate]

However when the mass rotates, the blocks that are added on are orientated incorrectly:
[image: The one closest to the camera was added after the mass rotated]

This got my whole family stumped, but it's gotta be possible.

Comment: You can use localroations instead

Answer (score 1):

You need to align the other axes as well.

So you could use the hit.normal as the new up direction for the GameObject, and then calculate the other axes based on that:

```
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(cameraTransform.position, cameraTransform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, buildingRange, buildable.value))
{
    // Indicator to show where the item will be placed
    buildBall.SetActive(true);
    buildBall.transform.position = hit.point;

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        // Create the item
        GameObject buildItem = Instantiate(currentItem, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);

        // Set the item's position
        buildItem.transform.position = hit.point;

        // Calculate the rotation based on the hit.normal and a reference direction
        Vector3 referenceDirection = Vector3.up; // You can change this to your desired reference direction
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal, referenceDirection);

        // Apply the rotation to the buildItem
        buildItem.transform.rotation = rotation;

        // Connect the buildItem object to the hit.collider.gameObject
    }
}
```

Comment: Completely agree, `hit.normal` is the way to go: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-normal.html

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work, it places the object always pointing up when on a certain side of the rectangle (I dunno how that happens). I think what is going wrong is that since forward and right are vectors, and so are transform.forward and transform.right, it completely overrides whatever changes are made prior. I ran into this issue as well, for transform.up = hit.normal sets the x,y, and z of the buildItem to hit.normal, getting rid of whatever calculations were applied before.

Comment: I made a new version this time calculating the rotation using Quaternion.LookRotation. Maybe it'll have a different outcome, let me know!